# How to define a Fortran subroutine which has the same name as an external subroutine?

Tags: python, fortran, blas, f2py

I want to wrap some BLAS functions into a Python module. For example to wrap the function `sswap`, I create a `.f95` file with the content

```
subroutine wrap_sswap(n, x, y, x_rows, y_rows)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real, intent(inout) :: x(x_rows), y(y_rows)

    integer :: x_rows, y_rows, incx = 1, incy = 1

    external :: sswap

    call sswap(n, x, incx, y, incy)
end subroutine wrap_sswap
```

Then I use `numpy.f2py` to create a python module `my_module` so that in Python I can call `my_module.wrap_sswap()`. This works nicely. However, I would like to be able to call `my_module.sswap()`, i.e., I want to name the subroutine `sswap` which would be the same name as the external BLAS function `sswap`. This is not possible and leads to an error `EXTERNAL attribute conflicts with SUBROUTINE attribute`.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Is your BLAS library based on Fortran or C code?  Why use a wrapper instead of directly calling the BLAS routine?

Comment: I compiled OpenBLAS and call the corresponding sswap. Let's say in this example I would not want to specify incx and incy whenever I call sswap because I know them to be equal to 1 all the time. So I would wrap this sswap plus make it available in Python.

Comment: In that case, a wrapper simply adds a layer of indirection to avoid passing `incx` and `incy`, and more importantly, you cannot make `sswap` a generic routine.

Comment: Though a workaround, maybe add an alias like "my_module.sswap = my_module.wrap_sswap" on the python side? (Btw, I'm wondering if it is no problem to let x_rows, y_rows have the SAVE attribute (implicitly via incx = 1)?)

Comment: That's an idea, yes. Let's say I have more generally an external function and I want two things: (1) I want to add a little bit of functionality to this external function and (2) I want to then call it from Python. Would it be possible to do so using the same name for the subroutine and for the external function? Or does Fortran provide no workaround other than renaming the subroutine? Can I import the external function under a different name?

Comment: You cannot use the same name for both a subroutine and function in a program.

Comment: Thank you, that's an answer to my question. So I guess there is also no way of importing sswap under a different name?

Comment: And, I am wondering if there is possibly a way to control a Python-exported name via f2py signature files or f2py command options? (not sure at all)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [roygvib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501546/roygvib), we can now provide a working example. It is based on the suggestion to change the f2py signature file.

Assume the code in the question above is saved in `sswap_ext.f95`. The first step is to generate a signature file:

```sh
f2py sswap_ext.f95 -m sswap_module -h sswap_ext.pyf
```

In my case, the generated signature file `sswap_ext.pyf` has the following content:

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module sswap_module ! in 
    interface  ! in :sswap_module
        subroutine wrap_sswap(n,x,y,x_rows,y_rows) ! in :sswap_module:sswap_ext.f95
            integer intent(in) :: n
            real dimension(x_rows),intent(inout) :: x
            real dimension(y_rows),intent(inout) :: y
            integer, optional,check(len(x)>=x_rows),depend(x) :: x_rows=len(x)
            integer, optional,check(len(y)>=y_rows),depend(y) :: y_rows=len(y)
        end subroutine wrap_sswap
    end interface 
end python module sswap_module

! This file was auto-generated with f2py (version:2).
! See http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/
```

The trick is now to replace every `wrap_sswap` with `sswap` and to add `fortranname wrap_sswap`, like so:

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module sswap_module ! in 
    interface  ! in :sswap_module
        subroutine sswap(n,x,y,x_rows,y_rows) ! in :sswap_module:sswap_ext.f95
            fortranname wrap_sswap
            integer intent(in) :: n
            real dimension(x_rows),intent(inout) :: x
            real dimension(y_rows),intent(inout) :: y
            integer, optional,check(len(x)>=x_rows),depend(x) :: x_rows=len(x)
            integer, optional,check(len(y)>=y_rows),depend(y) :: y_rows=len(y)
        end subroutine sswap
    end interface 
end python module sswap_module

! This file was auto-generated with f2py (version:2).
! See http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/
```

Now we can compile:

```sh
f2py -c sswap_ext.pyf sswap_ext.f95 /path/to/blas.a
```

We can then use `sswap_module.sswap` in Python:

```py
>>> import sswap_module
>>> print(sswap_module.sswap.__doc__)
sswap(n,x,y,[x_rows,y_rows])

Wrapper for ``sswap``.

Parameters
----------
n : input int
x : in/output rank-1 array('f') with bounds (x_rows)
y : in/output rank-1 array('f') with bounds (y_rows)

Other Parameters
----------------
x_rows : input int, optional
    Default: len(x)
y_rows : input int, optional
    Default: len(y)

>>> import numpy as np
>>> x, y = np.arange(4, dtype=np.float32), -np.arange(4, dtype=np.float32)
>>> sswap_module.sswap(2, x, y)
>>> x, y
(array([-0., -1.,  2.,  3.], dtype=float32), array([ 0.,  1., -2., -3.], dtype=float32))
```

Answer (score 1):

(Just for the record of a possible 2nd approach :-)

Though not strictly portable, another approach may be to use `bind(C,name="sswap_")` by assuming the C-exported name to be `sswap_` (in libblas.a etc). For example...

```
!! mylib.f90

module mymod
contains

subroutine sswap(n, x, y, x_rows, y_rows)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n, x_rows, y_rows
    real, intent(inout) :: x(x_rows), y(y_rows)

    integer, save :: incx = 1, incy = 1
    interface
        subroutine sswap_extern(n, x, incx, y, incy) bind(C,name="sswap_")
            integer :: n, incx, incy
            real    :: x(n), y(n)
        end
    end interface

    call sswap_extern(n, x, incx, y, incy)
end

end module
```

and we use f2py as usual:

```
$ python3.8 -m numpy.f2py -c mylib.f90 -m mylib
or
$ python3.8 -m numpy.f2py -c mylib.f90 -m mylib -L/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.10_1/lib -lopenblas   # on Mac + Homebrew
```

Then,

```
$ python3.8
>>> import mylib
>>> print( mylib.mymod.sswap.__doc__ )
sswap(n,x,y,[x_rows,y_rows])

Wrapper for ``sswap``.

Parameters
----------
n : input int
x : in/output rank-1 array('f') with bounds (x_rows)
y : in/output rank-1 array('f') with bounds (y_rows)

Other Parameters
----------------
x_rows : input int, optional
    Default: len(x)
y_rows : input int, optional
    Default: len(y)

>>> x, y = np.arange(4, dtype=np.float32), -np.arange(4, dtype=np.float32)
>>> mylib.mymod.sswap( 2, x, y )
>>> x
array([-0., -1.,  2.,  3.], dtype=float32)
>>> y
array([ 0.,  1., -2., -3.], dtype=float32)
```